# Slow boot after partition resize (editing fstab not working)

Tags: boot, partitioning, fstab

I know this question has been asked many times, but I have read a lot of websites but still haven't found an answer. 
Yesterday, I resized my root partition and my /home partition as well. Because of that, I deleted my swap partition and created it again.
Since that, my laptop needs around one minute in order to boot, and before that, it just needed 8 seconds. I've edited the /etc/fstab file with the new UUID of my swap partition, but the boot is still slow.
This is my fstab file:

```
# /dev/sda1
UUID=f78bb7c0-aaf9-4a17-971e-f8f75502b117   /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1

# /dev/sda3
UUID=efc3916d-81dc-4d77-b8dd-5f4599955461   /home       ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 2

# /dev/sda2
UUID=ab80c0ec-4311-4b8b-8b5b-a1b9cbf843a7   none        swap        defaults    0 0
```

And this is my blkid -o list output:

```
device                    fs_type    label       mount point                   UUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1                 ext4                   /                             f78bb7c0-aaf9-4a17-971e-f8f75502b117
/dev/sda2                 swap                   [SWAP]                        ab80c0ec-4311-4b8b-8b5b-a1b9cbf843a7
/dev/sda3                 ext4                   /home                         efc3916d-81dc-4d77-b8dd-5f4599955461
```

Btw, I've already checked the alignment of my partition and all of them are OK. Any idea? Thnaks in advance

UPDATE: systemd-analyze critical-chain output

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @7.681s
└─multi-user.target @7.681s
  └─vmware.service @6.374s +1.306s
    └─network-online.target @6.372s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @858ms +5.512s
        └─NetworkManager.service @784ms +70ms
          └─dbus.service @678ms
            └─basic.target @669ms
              get @669ms
                └─avahi-daemon.socket @669ms
                  └─sysinit.target @667ms
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @534ms +133ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @512ms +19ms
                        └─local-fs.target @509ms
                          └─home.mount @495ms +13ms
                            └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-efc3916d\x2d81dc\x2d4d77\x2db8dd\x2d5f4599955461.service @452ms +42ms
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-efc3916d\x2d81dc\x2d4d77\x2db8dd\x2d5f4599955461.device @438ms└─sockets.tar
```

Comment: Use `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and verify the time spend by `systemd-remount-fs.service` or whether another service is the culprit. Also, enter the command `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` and verify the same UUID's are found as in `blkid`. Actually, in my system the `blkid` command doesn't show the swap.

Comment: @WillemK I updated my post with the output of systemd-analyze critical-chain. I don't have any experience with UNIX services, so I hope you could review the results. The UUIDs shown by ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid match with the others. Thanks for you time.

Comment: I'm confused. The output shows your graphical desktop session is ready for use after 7.681 seconds, which coincides with the `8 seconds` remark but contradicts the `around one minute` ?  Did you give the systemd command AFTER you experienced the 1 minute boot time? Are you AutoStarting any programs ?