# Boot taking minutes following upgrade to 18.10

Tags: boot, 18.10, cryptsetup

Following the upgrade to 18.10, my laptop is taking about 3 minutes to boot up, previously it was about 15 seconds. The boot screen appears with the message "cryptsetup waiting for encrypted device / swapfile"
when it vanishes, the laptop boots into initramfs, when I enter "exit" the laptop boots as normal.
The boot log is clear apart from this message

```
[  OK  ] Started Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1.
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
See 'systemctl status swapfile.swap' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap.
```

When I enter 'systemctl status swapfile.swap' I get this message

```
Unit swapfile.swap could not be found.
```

Can you help?

/etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdc7 during installation
UUID=faef8f0b-bf61-4540-ac7d-25fc1b15b6b7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=D234-7542  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
# /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

/etc/crypttab file is empty

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076350/16-04-slow-to-boot If not please update your question with contents of `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: thanks for the link, I checked /etc/crypttab but it was empty
Updated question with contents of /etc/fstab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved itself when I upgraded to the 4.18.0-11 kernel, and there was an error message to remove the cryptsetup-initramfs module, so I removed it and the laptop is starting correctly now